# Deleted the shortcut icon from the 'files' forlder of Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, favicon

While working with drupal 7, by mistake, I deleted the image file that I set for 'Custom Shortcut Icon', Now the settings page of theme is displaying 'Invalid favicon path'. I placed another copy of the same image with same name at it's location. But this didn't worked. Changing the icon from theme settings page is also not allowed (displaying 'invalid favicon path') What should I do now?

the name of the older image file is still being displayed in the shortcut icon settings text field (on Appearance>>Theme settings page).

Comment: Did you try clearing Drupal's cache?

Comment: I cleared all cache but still the problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have a habit of caching these icons pretty hard, but if you go to Appearance > Settings and under "Shortcut icon settings" enter a new path or upload a new image and save, it usually clears it out.

Comment: It is not accepting new path or uploads. Uploads are completing, but still 'Invalid favicon path' is being displayed, and the newly uploaded file is just lying in the 'file' folder without being used in settings.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you deleting the image was the problem to start with. You didn't change anything else? Perhaps check that file path settings are correct in Configuration > Media > File system.